# A question about integral.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f$ be continuous on $[0, \infty)$ and $\lim_{x \to\infty}f(x)=L$. Evaluate$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^2f(n-x)dx$$

My question is can the $\lim$ moves into the integral. Because it is a limit doesn't relate to $x$ so I think it can be moved into the integral. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are at least a couple situations in which you can move a limit through an integral. The first is uniform convergence and the second is using the dominated convergence theorem (or MCT theorem, actually). I am assuming you would only know of the first one.

Can you show that for all $\epsilon > 0$ there is a $N$ such that $n \geq N$ implies
$|f(n-x)-L|<\epsilon$ for all $x\in [0,1]$? This is uniform convergence.

Comment: What's with that stranded $\delta>0$?

Comment: @nayrb why must be uniformly convergent?

Comment: @PedroTamaroff, silly, silly error. I of course meant that.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: try a change of variable in the integral and argue that $f(x)\approx L$ for very large $x$.

In general, you cannot pass a limit under an integral sign. To do so requires a bit of analysis (i.e. knowledge that uniform continuity and limit commute or some measure theoretic concepts).

Answer (score 1):

Naively we expect that, 
$$ \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \int_0^2 f(n-x) dx = \int_0^2 \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} f(n-x) dx = \int_0^2 L dx = 2L $$

We have no justification for the above steps yet, but they do provide a candidate for the answer. Once we have that we can prove that it is the limit. First we make some substitutions to shuffle the dependence of the integral on $n$ to its bounds.

Let $\eta = n-x$ then, the lower bound becomes $n$ and the upper bound becomes $n-2$ this lead to,

$$ - \int_{n}^{n-2} f(\eta) d\eta = \int_{n-2}^{n} f(\eta) d\eta $$

Now we consider what $\displaystyle\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} f(x) = L$ means.

$\displaystyle\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty } f(x) = L$ tells us that for every $\epsilon$ there exists an $N$ such that $\vert f(x)-L \vert < \epsilon/2$ when $x > N$.

We now evaluate,

$$ \left \vert \int_0^2 f(n-x) dx - 2L \right \vert = \left \vert \int_{n-2}^{n} f(\eta) d\eta - 2L \right \vert  = \left \vert \int_{n-2}^{n} f(\eta) - \frac{2L}{(n)-(n-2)} d\eta \right \vert   = \left \vert \int_{n-2}^{n} f(\eta) - \frac{2L}{(n)-(n-2)} d\eta \right \vert =\left \vert \int_{n-2}^{n} f(\eta) - L d\eta \right \vert  \leq  \int_{n-2}^{n} \left \vert f(\eta) - L \right \vert d\eta   \leq max\lbrace \vert f(\eta) - L\vert \rbrace_{\eta \in [n-2,n]} \times 2 $$

Now let $n\gt N$,

$$ \left \vert \int_0^2 f(n-x) dx - 2L \right \vert  \leq max\lbrace \vert f(\eta) - L \vert \rbrace_{\eta \in [N-2,N]} \times 2 \leq (\epsilon/2)\times 2 = \epsilon $$

Or in other words $\displaystyle\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \int_0^2 f(n-x)dx = 2L$.